# fill a column with conditional date column in R

Tags: r

I need help to add a column in a database with information from other table.
So, i have a .txt like this (this table have information of the dates when change the clasificaiton of the companies):

[image: Table 1]
the name of this .txt is CLASIF.txt

Then I need to complete a second table (the principal database) where the historical clasification change depending of the date from the first table, like this:

[image: Table 2]
the name of the pincipal database is DATA.txt

how can i do it in R ???

Comment: IN the input it is 03/01, but in output it changed to 04/01.  Please check your input and output

Comment: It would be much more useful/helpful if you provided actual data and not an image of it. Several reasons: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Additionally, there can be nuances to the data (e.g., `character`-vs-`factor`, `character`-vs-`POSIXt`) that are not apparent in this format, often better to use `dput(head(x))` or make the data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`).

Comment: I'm unable to come up with a "rule" that allows one to go from the input to the output. You should explain in natural language what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the full date range can be expanded with a full-join/merge. This assumes that all dates are on the first of the month. The expanded range of dates, crossed with all unique `id`s

```r
daterange <- expand.grid(
  id = unique(x$id),
  date = seq.Date(min(x$date), max(x$date) + 31, by = "month"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Here are two implementations, depending on your style:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>%
  full_join(daterange, by = c("id", "date")) %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(clasif = zoo::na.locf(clasif)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#   id    date       clasif
#   <chr> <date>     <chr> 
# 1 A     2018-01-01 A     
# 2 A     2018-02-01 A     
# 3 A     2018-03-01 AAA   
# 4 A     2018-04-01 AAA   
# 5 B     2018-01-01 BBB   
# 6 B     2018-02-01 BBB   
# 7 B     2018-03-01 BBB   
# 8 B     2018-04-01 BBB
```

and

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
xDT <- copy(x)
setDT(xDT)
xDT <- merge(xDT, daterange, by = c("id", "date"), all = TRUE) %>%
  .[ order(id, date), ] %>%
  .[, clasif := zoo::na.locf(clasif), by = "id"]
```

(I use `magrittr` here to break the `data.table` flow into a more step-wise pipeline, mostly for a visual benefit. This is not required; depending on your preference, this can be piped DT-wise just as easily, e.g., `xDT[...][...][...]`.)

Both operate on the premise that after we do the merge, we end up with "holes" in the `clasif` column:

```r
x %>%
  full_join(daterange, by = c("id", "date"))
#   id       date clasif
# 1  A 2018-01-01      A
# 2  A 2018-03-01    AAA
# 3  B 2018-01-01    BBB
# 4  A 2018-02-01   <NA>
# 5  B 2018-02-01   <NA>
# 6  B 2018-03-01   <NA>
# 7  A 2018-04-01   <NA>
# 8  B 2018-04-01   <NA>
```

From here, `zoo::na.locf` (by `id`, order by `date`) fill in the holes.

---

Data:

```r
x <- data.frame(
  id = c("A", "A", "B"),
  date = c("01/01/2018", "03/01/2018", "01/01/2018"),
  clasif = c("A", "AAA", "BBB"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
x$date <- as.Date(x$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```